# Do I need hreflang link for a single language ssite?

Tags: html, href

My site does not have multiple languages - because of that would there be any benefit or harm in adding one? eg:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://www.rgraph.net" hreflang="en" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be some small harm in increasing the download page size slightly.  I don't think there is any benefit in your case.

Comment: A benefit would be that search engines know the language of the link target without actually loading that target and screen readers for blind people can inform the user about the language of the target before the user clicks/activates such a link.

Comment: That's a valid point.  I would think a browser would assume the language is the same unless otherwise specified.  Generally sites I've visiited link to the same language 99.99% of the time.